# Why is it snowing in a forest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I started building in a forest biome, no snow at all. Then, after awhile into the build, it starts snowing and the water in the area starts freezing. I am wondering how or why an area would change temperatures.

I would also like to note that occasionally the server likes to take a 16x16 area and revert it back to the way it was before I started building. It's made for some frustrating fixes of large structures.

Comment: You are clearly using a prerelease build, these behaviours could be bugs (not that full releases are bug free!)

Comment: I think that's a pretty awesome bug!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The biome generator has changed between different game updates, and the server is assigning a biome based on the seed, but not generating new terrain.

I have several desert areas discovered during alpha that are now considered tundra or arctic, and are as such covered with snow.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case, since its hard to get the information from the person running the server, but this seems the most probable.

Comment: Just ask the server owner when the world was created and cross-reference that with beta version release dates.